# javascript collision detection (CSS transition)

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I'm building a simple game. There are 3 corona viruses moving randomly and a hero who tries to avoid hitting them. So far, I have corona viruses moving randomly but having hard time detecting the collision. I used CSS transition for moving the corona viruses. I want to game to be finished if a hero hits a virus while the virus is moving to a random point.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Corona invaders</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="background">
    <div id="henry"></div>
    <div id="corona"></div>
    <div id="corona1"></div>
    <div id="corona2"></div>
</div>
<div id='start'>
    <button id='btn-start'>Start</button>
</div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#background {
    background-image: url('assets/background.jpg');
    height: 700px;
    width: 1400px;
}

#henry {
    background-image: url(assets/henry.png);
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 700px;
}

#corona {
    background-image: url(assets/corona.png);
    height: 91px;
    width: 91px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: top 2s ease, left 2s ease;
}

#corona1 {
    background-image: url(assets/corona.png);
    height: 91px;
    width: 91px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: top 2s ease, left 2s linear;
}

#corona2 {
    background-image: url(assets/corona.png);
    height: 91px;
    width: 91px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: top 2s ease, left 2s ease;
}
```

Javascript

```
var henryLocation = {
    top: 700,
    left: 700
}

document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    // console.log(evt)
    if (evt.keyCode === 38 && henryLocation.top > 10) {
        henryLocation.top = henryLocation.top - 25
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 40 && henryLocation.top < 700) {
        henryLocation.top = henryLocation.top + 25
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 37 && henryLocation.left > 10) {
        henryLocation.left = henryLocation.left - 25
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 39 && henryLocation.left < 1360) {
        henryLocation.left = henryLocation.left + 25
    }
    moveHenry()
}

function moveHenry () {
    document.getElementById('henry').style.top = henryLocation.top + 'px'
    document.getElementById('henry').style.left = henryLocation.left + 'px'
}

const startBtn = document.getElementById('btn-start')
startBtn.addEventListener("click", theGame, false)

function theGame () {
    const startGame = setInterval(moveCorona, 1300)
    
    function moveCorona () {
    const theCorona = document.getElementById('corona')
    const theCorona1 = document.getElementById('corona1')
    const theCorona2 = document.getElementById('corona2')
    const w = 1300, h = 600

    theCorona.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 'px'
    theCorona.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * w) + 'px'
    theCorona1.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 'px'
    theCorona1.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * w) + 'px'
    theCorona2.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 'px'
    theCorona2.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * w) + 'px'
    
    function collisionDetect () {
        const theCorona = document.getElementById('corona')
        const theCorona1 = document.getElementById('corona1')
        const theCorona2 = document.getElementById('corona2')
        
        if (
            henryLocation.top <= theCorona.style.top + 91 &&
            henryLocation.top >= theCorona.style.top &&
            henryLocation.left <= theCorona.style.left + 91 &&
            henryLocation.left >= theCorona.style.left
            ) {
                alert('finish')
            }
    }
}
}




function gameLoop () {
    setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000)
    // moveHenry()
}

gameLoop()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can use **getBoundingClientRect()** to get the locations and sizes of the divs, which you can read about here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

We use it like this...

```
var H=henry.getBoundingClientRect();

var C=corona.getBoundingClientRect();
```

This now returns the following components respectively...

```
  H.left
  H.top
  H.width
  H.height

  C.left
  C.top
  C.width
  C.height
```

Here I attempt the collision logic...

```
 if(((H.left>=C.left)&&(H.left<=(C.left+C.width))&&(H.top>=C.top)&&(H.top<=(C.top+C.height))){

  // We have a collision

 }
```

NB: I typed the logic off the top of my head so there could be a boo-boo, but you get the drift of detecting a collision.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. The viruses are moving to random points and I believe collision will be detected when the virus and the hero are at the same point. However, I'm trying to detect collision when the virus hits the hero while it is moving.